# Pasar múltiples parámetros a través de una mutación usando vuex

Tags: vue.js

Quiero pasar más de un parámetro al presionar un botón y para ello uso una mutación y por lo que estuve investigando esto se hace pasando un objeto que contenga todo lo que quiero pasar.

Pondré un ejemplo para ilustrar mejor lo que quiero:

```
pasarDatos(state, nombreLocal) {
  state.nombre = nombreLocal
}
```

Aquí estaría asignando el valor del parámetro `nombreLocal` a mi variable nombre pero yo quiero pasar más de un dato y esta es la forma en la que vi como se hace:

```
pasarDatos(state, { nombre, apellido}) { 
  state.nombre = "qué debo poner aquí?";
  state.apellido = "qué debo poner aquí?";
}
```

Es que lo que pienso es que debo poner algo como `obj.nombre` y `obj.apellido`, pero en ningún momento le estoy poniendo un nombre a mi objeto así que no creo que sea así.

Si tienen una mejor forma de pasar más de un argumento agradecería que me dijeran, esa fue la forma que encontré.

Comment: Vuex solo recibe un parámetro, además del `state`. Es correcto lo que estás intentando hacer. Crea un objeto que tenga todos los valores que necesites y listo. Tal como dice @luis-briceño: ```pasarDatos(state, usuario) { 
   state.nombre = usuario.nombre;    
   state.apellido = usuario.apellido; 
}```

Answer (score 1):

Con el segundo caso que expones es suficiente para pasar varios parámetros. Y básicamente allí estás haciendo una descomposición. Es decir:

```
let obj = {
   nombre: "Luis",
   apellido: "Briceño"
}
let { nombre, apellido } = obj
```

Aquí estarías creando dos variables con esos valores de obj.

Haciendo referencia a qué debes colocar

```
pasarDatos(state, { nombre, apellido}) { 
   state.nombre=nombre;    
   state.apellido=apellido; 
}
```

También podrías con

```
pasarDatos(state, usuario) { 
   state.nombre=usuario.nombre;    
   state.apellido=usuario.apellido; 
}
```

O más avanzado:

```
pasarDatos(state, usuario ) { 
   state = { ...state, ...usuario }
}
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.